# android excessive global references

Tags: android, java-native-interface, emulation

I'm occassionally tripping the jni global reference limit for the android emulator.  I'm trying to store around 2000 words along with definitions in my application and it's failing at either of two spots:  if I use DOM to parse the xml file with all those references it fails when DOM pulls the tree into memory.  If I use SAX it fails when I get to around the 2000th element.

Does anyone have a link to how I can disable the check (I understand it doesn't exist on the actual machines and I am trying to persist 2000 small objects in memory)?  If not, is there a good way to debug this?  The objects that are building up are strings:

```
09-20 16:24:00.278: WARN/dalvikvm(625):  1879 of Ljava/lang/String; 28B (1877 unique)
```

I tried starting the avd with `-nojni` and using `adb` to set `dalvik.vm.checkjni`

```
C:\android-sdk-windows\tools>adb shell getprop dalvik.vm.checkjni
false
```

Although logcat shows "CheckJNI is Off", it stills dies a the globalref 2001 limit.

Also, after the parsing section, the memory winds up getting returned as I see:

```
09-20 16:31:23.238: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1157 objects / 48208 bytes in 147ms
09-20 16:31:23.258: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 1799
09-20 16:31:23.278: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 1699
09-20 16:31:23.287: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 1599
09-20 16:31:23.309: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 1499
09-20 16:31:23.328: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 1399
09-20 16:31:23.338: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 1299
09-20 16:31:23.367: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 1199
09-20 16:31:23.367: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 1099
09-20 16:31:23.398: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 999
09-20 16:31:23.398: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 899
09-20 16:31:23.408: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 799
09-20 16:31:23.418: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 699
09-20 16:31:23.418: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 599
09-20 16:31:23.437: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 499
09-20 16:31:23.447: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 399
09-20 16:31:23.447: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 299
09-20 16:31:23.469: DEBUG/dalvikvm(654): GREF has decreased to 199
```

So I don't think it's my hashmap holding the word objects that is actually the problem.  The only idea I have left is to cut the xml file into multiples, but that seems like a might inelegant solution.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried with the xmlpull parser?

Comment: Excellent call, I copied basically the same code over from the sax parser and although it runs 10 or 15% slower (matching what they say here http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/10927_3824221_2/Android-XML-Parser-Performance.htm) it completely clears up the issues with global jni references!

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the platform.  There's no reason for all those strings to be pinned in memory by native code.  Do you still have a copy of the APK that caused the problem?  I'd love to get a copy and see if the problem still exists.  (Attaching it to a bug report on b.android.com might be the easiest way to send it.)

Answer (score 2):

this is a bug in our expat-based XML parsers (both SAX and pull): http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12595

Answer (score 0):

Although slightly slower than sax, excessive global references seem to disappear when using the XML Pull Parser.